# Is there already a specification for the table format printed by the docker and kubectl commands?

Tags: docker, format, specifications, kubectl

I am making a parser/serializer of character based tables printed by docker and kubectl commands. Which specification should I see?

For example,

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID    Image    COMMAND     CREATED
6504c2385d77    abcd     "/bin/sh"   3 weeks ago
```

In my understanding, This table has the following characteristics.

- Field name can include single space.
- Field name can not include two or more consecutive spaces.
- In the first line, field names are separated by two or more spaces.
- The value of table row is started from the same column index with the corresponding field name.

Is there already well defined specification for such table format?

Answer (score 3):

Both [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/) and [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-overview/) have well-defined APIs with client libraries in several languages, and you should use these instead of trying to scrape the output of the command-line tools.  Both of these APIs are JSON-over-HTTP which should be easy to manage even without a dedicated client library.  Docker's transport is typically a local Unix socket which is a little exotic.

There aren't very many security controls in the Docker API, so consider that if you have this API access (and, equivalently, if you can run the `docker ps` command you show) then you can launch a container as root that bind-mounts the entire host filesystem and makes whatever changes you want to.  Kubernetes's RBAC system is more developed and can be configured to allow read-only access to selected resources.

Comment: Right, both docker and kubectl can manipulate the output using json query against the output from the API. It is better way to extract data rather than parsing the printed table.

Comment: But I would also like to make a new command line tool which prints pretty table. Since I love this table format, I would like to use the format in my command. Actually the command is not related to cloud and container area.